# Nested Elasticsearch queries

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to create a nested query which would filter out some documents with specific terms. In this case I'm trying to filter out documents which have matching terms in user.first. Data example:

```
{
  "group" : "fans",
  "user" : [ 
    {
      "first" : "John",
      "last" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first" : "Tim",
      "last" :  "White"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "group" : "fans",
  "user" : [ 
    {
      "first" : "Jim",
      "last" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first" : "Alice",
      "last" :  "Black"
    }
  ]
}
```

My query doesn't get the desired result as it returns me all records which are not filtered. I tried querying using:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": [
            {
                "nested": {
                    "query": {
                        "terms": {
                            "user.first": [
                                "John",
                                "Thomas"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "user"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I expect here to get documents which don't match with the filter. In this case it should return only the second document. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Do you expect that the document returns but without `John` in the `user` array?

Comment: It should return only the document with `Alice` in this case.

Comment: I missunderstood you a little bit and asked my question incorrectly. Please see the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I've managed to find a solution for the problem. This is the query that filters out documents we don't need.

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": [
            {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "query": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "user.first": [
                                            "John",
                                            "Thomas"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "path": "user"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```